# Is there a list of common Fn keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

While browsing shortcut list in system settings, I realized some of them are just words and relate to Fn keys. E.g.

- WWW
- Calculator
- Mail

I realize **those are not true Fn keys**, but rather **Fn functions**. There must be some Ubuntu component that map manufacturer/keyboard specific **Fn keys**, into those "unified" **Fn functions**.

What is complete list of **Fn functions** recognizable by Ubuntu's shortcuts configuration?

Comment: That totally depends on your keyboard.

Comment: It depends on the keyboard which you can use,  OP is asking about *a list of all such possibilities*... **Voted to leave open**  @Rinzwind

Comment: I've updated question, to distinguish between manufacturer/keyboard specific Fn **key** and Ubuntu unified Fn **functions** seen in shortcuts settings. I hope now it's clear I ask only about list of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions in general) adopts the symbols defined by [the XFree86 project](http://www.xfree86.org/). You can find a list of these symbols in [this wiki page](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/XF86_keyboard_symbols). The mapping from key to symbol for each keyboard model is done by [XKB](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/). Look in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`, for example:

```
// Logitech

// Logitech common definitions
hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "logitech_base" {
    include "inet(media_nav_acpi_common)"
    key <I02> { [ XF86HomePage ] };
    key <I15> { [ XF86Community ] };
    key <I16> { [ XF86ScrollClick ] };
    key <I21> { [ XF86VendorHome ] };
    key <I3B> { [ XF86New ] };
    key <I3C> { [ XF86Reply ] };
    key <I43> { [ XF86MyComputer ] };
    key <I44> { [ XF86Documents ] };
    key <I57> { [ XF86Pictures ] };
    key <I58> { [ XF86Music ] };
};
```